# JQuery/JSON: Can't get JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why can't I get this JSON when it's properly formatted?

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://sandbox.buscape.com/service/findProductList/564771466d477a4458664d3d/?keyword=drive&format=json", function(result){

        alert('ok');

    });
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your JSON response through a tool like http://jsonlint.com to verify that your JSON is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it comes from a different domain. You have to use JSONP, luckily the API you are using supports it (by setting the *callback* parameter):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    url : 'http://sandbox.buscape.com/service/findProductList/564771466d477a4458664d3d/?keyword=drive&format=json&callback=?',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery will actually add the `callback=?` to the URL for you if you set the `dataType` to `'jsonp'`. :-P

Comment: @user1091856: What do you mean "didn't work"?  It worked fine for me.

Comment: Of course it does. The JSFiddle logs the requested data in the console quite fine.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the accented characters in the file are causing problems. For instance, í shows up in `"Sistema Operacional Compatível"`. If the encoding is not correct, it will be seen as an invalid UTF-8 character. Make sure that the encoding is correct, or manually encode to UTF-8.